# How to add a sub document to sub document array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mogodb like this:

```js
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5393006538efaae30ec2d458"),
"userName" : "shiva",
"userUnderApiKey" : 123456,
"groups" : [
    {
        "groupName" : "Default",
        "groupMembers" : [ ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to add a new group in the groups array as sub document, like the below

```js
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5393006538efaae30ec2d458"),
"userName" : "shiva",
"userUnderApiKey" : 123456,
"groups" : [
    {
        "groupName" : "Default",
        "groupMembers" : [ ]
    },

    {
        "groupName" : "Family",
        "groupMembers" : [ ]
    }
]
}
```

How to insert new sub document in the array of sub documents.Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add a new member to the array you just use [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as you normally would:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("5393006538efaae30ec2d458") },
    { 
        "$push": {
            "groups": {
                "groupName" : "Family",
                "groupMembers" : [ ]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

If you then wanted to add members to the array that member contains then you need to match the element you want to add to:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5393006538efaae30ec2d458"),
        "groups.groupName" : "Family",
    },
    { 
        "$push": {
            "groups.$.groupMembers" : "bill"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Perfectly working, Can you please post removing a member from `groupMembers` and removing a group from `groups` list.It is more useful for new learners like me, Thank you once again

Comment: @Mulagala The best source for you is the documentation such as referenced by the link to the `$push` operator as was given. The option you want to remove is `$pull` and there are various samples included in the documentation. If you have problems understanding the documentation or how to apply it to a specific problem, then please feel free to post another question. After searching for existing answers that is.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be interested in [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

> The $push operator appends a specified value to an array.

and [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array only if the value is not already in the array. If the value is in the array, $addToSet does not modify the array.

you can find examples in the documents above. It would be something like:

```
db.collection.update({
    _id: ObjectId("5393006538efaae30ec2d458")
}, {
    $push: {
        groups: {
            "groupName": "Family",
            "groupMembers": []
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can I use the `$push` operator to push into an array of sub-documents, which is itself inside another array of sub-documents? Essentially, one more level of nesting than in the quoted example of this question. I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155298/how-to-update-mongodb-documents-with-arrays-of-sub-documents) on SO just today about this.